# Phrase "Out of league"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Does it mean the same thing? If not so, then how to say that I am better than her.

> I'm out of your league
>
> You are out of my league

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not mean or imply the same thing.

It is a sporting reference often used as an analogy. Professional sports tournaments are normally organised into *leagues*, pitting similarly performing teams against one another. When a team reaches the very top of a league, they may be promoted to the next league up; likewise, when they hit the bottom, they may be demoted/relegated.

In the context of *dating*, "out of one's league" idiomatically means that a person is *superior* to you and would not be interested in dating someone who was not at a similar level. It could be applied to degrees of *perceived beauty*, *social status*, *class*, or *intelligence*.

If someone said "she's out of your league", it would imply that you are not good enough to date that person, for whatever perceived reason.

Your examples are a little different, as they appear to be said *to* the person they are also *about*. Saying "you are out of my league" would be a compliment of sorts, but is also *self-deprecating*. I imagine one would say that in the hope that the other person says "no you're not" and then they live happily ever after.

"I'm out of your league" would be a *vain boast* - saying that you are better than someone else and that they are not worth dating.

The expression is also used in other figurative contexts - for example when comparing hardware (eg *you cannot compare these two cars - one is out of the other's league!*)

Comment: OK, what does "I am out of my league" mean? When I play chess with my dad, I am out of my league. (A dictionary example)

Comment: @user1425 That's not particularly idiomatic - I think you might need the phrase "I'm out of my depth", or perhaps "I'm punching above my weight".

Comment: But I come across it often.

Comment: @user1425 People often mix up idioms. Even native speakers. It doesn't make any sense because, if you read my answer, when someone else is 'out of [your] league' it means they are higher than you. How can YOU be out of YOUR league?

Comment: That's exactly what I am wondering about. When I read it here I felt confounded. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20her%20league

Comment: @user1425 Well, that surprises me... Websters is predominantly a US English dictionary, and I'm a BrEng speaker, so perhaps it is more idiomatic in the US? It isn't precisely what this question was about, perhaps pose it as a question and see if a US speaker can respond.